# Ford Explorer 2014 child seat in second row middle seat

Tags: ford, explorer, child-seat

Is it possible to have rear facing child seat in middle row middle seat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoke with ford they said no

Disappointed middle seat is horrible design no way a normal person can sit comfortably

My recommendation when buying 7 seater take 7 people with you so you can test all seats